# Python ConfigParser module fails to find section

Tags: python, parsing, config

I'm using Python 2.6 to write in an .ini file, called config.ini. Here's my code:

```
def saveConfig(self, selection, value, bool):
    Config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    Config.read("config.ini")
    Config.set(selection, value, bool)
    with open('config.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        Config.write(configfile)
```

It's ok so far, but when I run my script (thus the function `self.saveConfig('Config', 'testoption', 'True')`, I get the NoSectionError exception:

> ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'Config'

Which seems pretty weird as I actually have this section.

Here's my config.ini file:

```
[Config]
version = 0.1-unstable
testoption = False
testbool = True
```

I can read their values using the .get() method, but can not set different values. Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me.

However, the `RawConfigParser`'s `read()` method is a little weird, in that it won't raise an exception if it can't find the file - instead it returns a list of the files it managed to read.

Try something like this...

```
def saveConfig(self, selection, value, bool):
    Config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    if not Config.read("config.ini"):
        raise IOError, 'cannot load config.ini'
    Config.set(selection, value, bool)
    with open('config.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        Config.write(configfile)
```

Comment: Hah, great idea there, it returned IOError: cannot load config.ini, I'll try to change the path or something.